# Return values using EventEmitter angular2

Tags: angular, eventemitter, emit

I have an EventEmitter that issues an event in the parent component, I want it from the parent component to perform a series of instructions and the result returns it to the caller,
this.filteredList I want it to contain the list returned by the parent component but when it returns, filteredList is undefined

This is de chid component "autocomplete.component.ts:"
//When returns in this.changeFilter.emit, this.filteredList is undefined:

```
export class AutocompleteComponent implements OnInit {
    ...

    public filteredList = [];

    @Output() changeFilter = new EventEmitter<any>();


    filter(){
     //This is where I want the filteredList to contain the list returned by the other component:
     this.filteredList =this.changeFilter.emit({query:this.query}); 
     if (filteredList){
        console.log(filteredList); 
      }
    }
```

the template:

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <input id="clienteAut" type="text" class="form-control bs-autocomplete" style="width:300px;" [(ngModel)]="query" (keyup)="filter()" on-click="filterAll()">
      <label for="clienteAut"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="divLista" *ngIf="filteredList.length > 0" style="">
      <div class="divFila" *ngFor="let item of filteredList">
        <ul >
          <li>
            <a (click)="select(item)">{{item.CodigoCliente}} - {{item.Nombre}}</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

This is the parent component "busquedacompiadoras.component.ts":

//The function "onChangeFilterClientes" return a list with data, but when it returns to the eventEmitter of the child component this.filteredList is undefined
//Any ideas?

```
export class BusquedaCopiadorasComponent {  

clientes: Array<any> //= [];

ngOnInit() {
    this._comunService.getMarcas()
        .subscribe((clientesData) => {
            this.clientes = clientesData as clienteModel[];
            //this.rellenarMarcas(marcasData);
        });
}    

onChangeFilterClientes(obj:any):any[]{        
     this.clientesFilter = this.clientes.filter(c => c.Nombre.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(obj.query)>-1);       
     return this.clientesFilter; 
}
```

Comment: Because `EventEmitter` is bases on `Observable` and the action is async (happens later, when your current chunk of sync code is completed). You need to check for example`ngOnChanges` to get notified about when value updates have happened.

Comment: Define `filteredList` as an `@Input()` instead, and just set it in the parent. No need to return any value from `onChangeFilterClientes`. Pass `clientesFilter` to the child `[filteredList]="clientesFilter"` (HTML)

Comment: Sorry but I don´t understand, you could give an example of your explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

export class AutocompleteComponent implements OnInit {
    ...

```
@Input() public filteredList = [];

@Output() changeFilter = new EventEmitter<any>();


filter(){
 //This is where I want the filteredList to contain the list returned by the other component:
 this.changeFilter.emit({query:this.query}); 
}
```

And in the BusquedaCopiadorasComponent template pass the filteredList as below:

```
 [filteredList]="clientesFilter"
```